# More specific template deduction

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++17, template-specialization

I have primary template and three partial specializations, that the compiler considers as ambiguous:

```
#include <vector>

template<typename ... ARGS>
struct queryBuilder;

template<typename INTERNALDATA,
         template<typename> typename ICONTAINER,
         template <typename> typename ECONTAINER>
struct queryBuilder<ECONTAINER<ICONTAINER<INTERNALDATA>>>
{ };

template<typename PARAM,
         template<typename> typename T>
struct queryBuilder<T<PARAM>>
{ };

template<typename PARAM1,
         typename PARAM2,
         template<typename,typename> typename T>
struct queryBuilder<T<PARAM1, PARAM2>>
{ };

template<typename T>
struct queryBuilder<T>
{ };

int main() {
  queryBuilder<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> q; // error: ambiguous
}
```

I'm using g++ 7.3.0 with -std=c++17.

Everything works just fine if we, as suggested in comments, provide allocators parameters for both containers in first specialization.

Comment: `std::vector` has more than one template parameter (even if one is defaulted), so `template <typename>` isn't a match.

Comment: "Compiler finds them ambiguous". Can't  reproduce this behavior. What's the compiler?

Comment: @songyuanyao g++ 7.3.0

Comment: are you compiling C++17, C++14 or C++11?

Comment: @max66  im using c++17

Comment: @BoPersson: Even in C++17 ?

Comment: Well, [P0522R0 Matching of template template-arguments](https://wg21.link/p0522) *should* be implemented in g++ 7, allowing default parameters. So perhaps this is some other corner case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have three specializations that match here (thanks to [new rules in C++17](https://wg21.link/p0522) that allow using default arguments):

```
1) A<B<C>> (with A = std::vector, B = std::vector, C = int)
2) A<B>    (with A = std::vector, B = std::vector<int> )
3) A<B,C>  (with A = std::vector, B = std::vector<int>, C = std::allocator<int>)
```

Which of these is more specialized than the others? Well, #1 is more specialized than #2 (since *any* single parameter works in #2 but only class template specializations with one parameter work in #1), so that's good.

But neither #1 nor #3 is more specialized - the `A`s take different numbers of template parameters so that just doesn't work. And neither #2 nor #3 is more specialized - for the same reason.

Since you can't say which is the *most* specialized of these cases, deduction is ambiguous. You could really mean any of them.

You need to rethink the specializations you're doing here.